# rm: cannot remove ‘icons.css’: Permission denied (Centos 7)

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, file-permissions

I need to delete files but permission is denied. Even rm -rf command can't delete these files. I logged in as a root user. I've also tried

```
# rm -rf icons.css
rm: cannot remove ‘icons.css’: Permission denied
# chattr -a -i icons.css
# chown -hR root:root icons.css
# chmod 777 icons.css
# lsattr -d icons.css
-------------e-- icons.css
```

After all that problem not resolved

```
# rm -rf icons.css
rm: cannot remove ‘icons.css’: Permission denied
```

Why I can't delete that file?

Comment: Please format your post.

Comment: Please include a regular `ls` for the file and the directory it's residing in. You need to be able to modify the directory to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, check permission of its `root directory`. Like if it is present under `/data/icons.css`. Check attributes of `/data` and check

Example -

```
lsattr /data
```